# Complete Include Build Link Details

Tags: cmake

We have a project which we compile it thru CMAKE utility. Our projects has submodules and recently it was found that developers where introducing code dependency across sub modules.

Say we have submodule A and submodule B while main module C compiles both A and B and generates all the executable.  As per the issue submodule B code is being used in submodule A. Though the code is compiling fine but this is highly dangerous of the dependency across sub modules.

Now how can I know via CMAKE (logs / report / traces / build etc anyway) utility which includes path / link paths are involved in which binaries. The over all objective is to break the dependency if any.

Is there a way to get any kind of details via CMAKE build process - the include / linking path level used for each binary (to trace libs across submodules being used for binaries)?

Comment: `VERBOSE=1 make` after configuring some CMake project will output all the commands executed during compilation and linking. Would that help in your case?

Comment: I ran the command cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON . in the directory where we start the main build but it stated CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE

Comment: have you tried to check `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and `LINKED_LIBRARIES` of your submodules with help of `get_target_property`?